# Unable to access register variable in tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using Ansible 2.4 to create a playbook. But, I'm experiencing a `server not defined` error in one of my tasks and I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

I have a the following task in `playbook.yml` that spins up a server on digital ocean. I create a variable called `server` that contains the response.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Spinning up a new droplet
    digital_ocean:
      state: present
      command: droplet
      name: "{{ domain }}"
      ssh_key_ids:
        - "{{ ssh_key_id }}"
      size_id: 512mb
      region_id: lon1
      image_id: debian-9-x64
      api_token: "{{ api_token }}"
      backups_enabled: no
    register: server
```

If I try to access `server` within the playbook it will work fine. But if I try to access the variable within a tasks that I include it reports `server` is undefined. I use roles to separate my tasks/handlers etc.

The directory structure is:

```
/
  - group_vars
    - all.yml
  - roles
    - node-servers
      - tasks
        - main.yml
        - haproxy.yml
        ...
```

In `playbook.yml` I have the following:

```
- hosts: node-servers
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - node-servers

  handlers:
    - name: Restarting haproxy
      service:
        name: haproxy
        state: restarted
```

In `roles/node-servers/tasks/main.yml` I have the following:

```
---
  - debug:
    var: "{{server}}"

  - name: Creating unprivileged user
    user:
      name: "{{ user }}"
      state: present
      password: "{{ user_pass }}"

  - name: Updating packages
    shell: apt-get update

  - name: Installing Required packages
    apt: name={{ item }} state=latest
    with_items:
      - build-essential
      - iptables-persistent
      - apt-transport-https
      - python-openssl

  - include: nodejs.yml
  - include: haproxy.yml
  - include: letsencrypt-dns.yml
  - include: deploy.yml
  - include: daemonize-nodeapp.yml
```

`servers` returns as undefined.

How can I access `server` from within `roles/node-servers/tasks/main.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `register`, the data is registered only for the current host (`localhost` in your case). This way, you can have different value on each host.

If you want to access the variables of another host (of the group `node-servers` in your case), you have to use `hostvars`:

```
{{ hostvars.localhost.server }}
```

[Magic Variables, and How To Access Information About Other Hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

Comment: Is the `hostvars` variable automatically available in the tasks? Such as in `haproxy.yml`? Or do I have to define a variable in `node-servers`? I get `hostvars` undefined when debugging in `haproxy.yml`.

Comment: The `hostvars` is available everywhere anytime. BUT it's content is depending on the order of the tasks: you cannot access `hostvars.localhost.foo` before setting var/fact `foo` on `localhost`.

Comment: Works now. I was doing `var={{ hostvars }}` instead of `var=hostvars`.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you want to add the newly created server to your inventory. You can do this by using `add_host` module (see [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html)).

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Spinning up a new droplet
    digital_ocean:
      state: present
      # ...
    register: result

  - add_host:
      name: "{{ result.droplet.ip_address }}"
      groups: node-servers
      droplet_details: "{{ result.droplet }}"
```

Now you can configure the server by referencing the `node-servers` group.

```
- hosts: node-servers
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - node-servers
```

And in your role access your droplet details:

```
---
- debug:
    var: "{{ droplet_details }}"
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I already do this. I didn't post the entire play. The answer above solved this issue.

Comment: Ok, so you want to access the droplet details returned by the `digital_ocean` module in the `node-servers` role, right? See my edits, I updated the answer accordingly.